# Gulp build into Docker container when NODE_ENV=production

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, gitlab

I have a **Docker container** that host a **NodeJS** Web application.

This docker container has the environment variable `NODE_ENV=production`

When I run the container, npm install skip all the `devDependencies` from the `package.json` file because of that.

I thought 3 differents solutions but none seems good

1. Store the `build` on my CVS
2. Build outside docker
3. Move all devDependencies to dependencies

Choice 1 take storage on CVS, and look stupid

Choice 2 require to have NodeJS, npm, gulp and many other libs installed

Choice 3 Looks the best

But i am interested in any others suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ok, i found a solution !

My node APP in production require the env var `NODE_ENV=production`

So I've edited the docker file and **removed** the line

```
ENV NODE_ENV production
```

I've updated **CMD** to

```
CMD ['./start.sh']
```

Here is the `./start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
gulp build
export NODE_ENV=production
nodemon server -p80
```

Answer (score 12):

Another solution to these sorts of situations is passing NODE_ENV as a build argument:

```
docker build --build-arg NODE=development --rm -t some/name  .
```

For anyone running into issues passing NODE_ENV as a build-arg...try just passing it as NODE (as is done above) or some other name, instead. And in your Dockerfile you can use it like so:

```
ARG NODE=production
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE}
RUN npm start
```

Note, in the code above, `production` is the default, but you can override it with `--build-arg NODE=development`.